# Regular expression to validate whether the data contains numeric ( or empty is also valid)

Tags: sql, regex, validation

i have to validate the data contains numeric or not and if it is not numeric return 0 and if it is numeric or empty return 1.

Below is my query i tried in SQL.

`SELECT dbo.Regex('^[0-9]','123')` -- This is returning 1.

`SELECT dbo.Regex('^[0-9]','')`    -- this is not returning 1 but i want to return as 1 and i try to put space in "pattern" also it is not working...

please can any one help....

Thanks in advance

Comment: I added the sql tag since you are using sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT dbo.Regex('^[0-9]*$','123')
```

or better yet:

```
SELECT dbo.Regex('^\d*$','123')
```

`\d` is standard shorthand for `[0-9]`. Note that when you use `[0-9]` it means "match exactly one digit. The `*` wildcard means match zero or more so `\d*` means match zero or more digits, which includes an empty result.

Comment: +1. But to be precise, with some regex engines, `\d` can match "digits" from other languages in Unicode as well, so be aware that it is not always _exactly_ equivalent to: `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

Your Regex is not quite right: `"^[0-9]"` checks only, if the first character in the string is a number. Your regex would return `1` on "3abcde".

Use

```
"^\d*$"
```

to check if the field contains only numbers (or nothing). If you want to allow whitespace, use

```
"^\s*\d*\s*$"
```

If you want to allow signs and decimals, try

```
"^\s*(+|-)?\d*\.?\d*\s*$"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens. After seeing `"^\d*$"`, I tried making it more readable, at least to non regex experts like me, and got `"^[1-9]*$"`. In my case I need numbers from 1 to 9 at any time or have it empty. Look at it [Online C# regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Answer (score 0):

Try `^[0-9]*$`, which will match 0 or more digits only:

```
SELECT dbo.Regex('^[0-9]*$','')
```

should return 1, as should...

```
SELECT dbo.Regex('^[0-9]*$','123')
```